# R: Implication of tibble inheritance

Tags: r, oop, dplyr, tibble

I try to understand the behaviour of inheriting tibble class and face the following situation. I create a class `myClass` for which I define a print function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

myClass<-function(x,y,var){
new_tibble(data.frame(x=x,y=y),oneVar=var,subclass='myClass')}

myObj=myClass(rnorm(10),rnorm(10),'s')
myObj2=myClass(rnorm(10),rnorm(10),'s2')


print.myClass<-function(x,...){
 print(as_tibble(x))
   print(slot(x,'oneVar'))
 }
```

Then, let try to use some dplyr functions modfying my object:

```
myObj %>% arrange(x) %>% filter(x>0)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
      x       y
  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 0.183  0.826 
2 0.801  0.504 
3 1.19   2.53  
4 1.24   0.238 
5 1.28  -0.0557
6 1.69  -0.734 
[1] "s"
```

It looks like that calling `filter` and `arrange` just modifies the tibble part of my object remaining other slots unchanged, which may be a usefull property to exploit.

Then let make something less obvious, let "row_bind"s two myClass objects:

```
bind_rows(myObj,myObj2)
# A tibble: 20 x 2
         x       y
     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  0.801   0.504 
 2  1.19    2.53  
 3 -1.69    0.549 
 4  1.24    0.238 
 5 -0.109  -1.05  
 6 -0.117   1.29  
 7  0.183   0.826 
 8  1.28   -0.0557
 9 -1.73   -0.784 
10  1.69   -0.734 
11 -0.216  -1.31  
12 -0.335  -0.600 
13 -1.09   -0.129 
14 -0.0854  0.887 
15  1.07   -0.151 
16 -0.145   0.330 
17 -1.17   -3.23  
18 -0.819  -0.772 
19  0.685   0.287 
20 -0.320  -1.22  
Error in slot(x, "oneVar") : 
  no slot of name "oneVar" for this object of class "myClass"
```

Here the "oneVar" slot is missing and thus the integrity of the "myClass" object is broken. I understand, that this is behaviour is not necessarly a problem but try to understand where does it come from.

Then comes my question:

which mecanism(s) involved in the `bind_rows` (not involved in e.g. `filter`) makes the loss of the slot?
 and how does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like `bind_rows` is not designed for keeping the user-defined slots. On the other hand, the base R `rbind` keeps the slot and use the one from the first object as follows. I also tried `data.table::rbindlist(list(myObj, myObj2))`, but the output is not `myClass` anymore. This is just how these functions were created with different requirements and behaviors.

```
rbind(myObj, myObj2)
# # A tibble: 20 x 2
#   x       y
#   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 -0.0978   0.629 
# 2  0.406   -0.889 
# 3  0.766   -0.746 
# 4 -0.715    0.872 
# 5  0.617    1.05  
# 6  0.353   -1.49  
# 7 -0.595   -1.41  
# 8 -3.20    -0.262 
# 9 -1.33     0.232 
# 10  0.835   -0.751 
# 11 -0.00793  0.807 
# 12  0.177    0.680 
# 13 -1.10     0.857 
# 14 -0.679    1.79  
# 15 -1.38     0.0481
# 16 -1.42     1.02  
# 17 -1.97     0.732 
# 18  1.72     1.06  
# 19 -0.773   -0.594 
# 20  0.490    0.186 
# [1] "s"
```